# Проблема с сессией в PHP

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, backend

Ситуация такая: был написан сайт и залит на хост, проблем с подключением к базе данных, сессией не было вообще. Стало необходимо перенести этот же сайт на другой домен. Я использовал рег.ру. Я создал копию всех файлов, отвязал домен от хоста, потом привязал нужный, зашёл в панель управления и залил свои файлы обратно(*я ничего не менял в коде*).

Захожу на сайт goodzone.site (*ни в коем случае не реклама, проект лично для узкого круга лиц*) и встречаю проблему, во первых:

```
Ignoring session_start() because a session is already active...
```

Погуглил в инете, нашёл решение, в месте ошибки я заменил простое подключение к сессии на подключение с предварительной проверкой:

```
    <?php
        session start() // БЫЛО
    ?>
```

```
    <?php
        // СТАЛО:
        if(!isset($_SESSION))
        {
            session_start();
        }
    ?>
```

**Тут возникает сам вопрос, почему такого не было раньше, сайт работал целый месяц и подобной ситуации не возникало?**

Давайте рассмотрим ситуацию дальше, может для опытного программиста появятся зацепки:
У меня на сайте в начале каждого файла запускается сессия. По ходу пользования туда записываются ошибки по типу "неправильный логин или пароль", потом эти данные вытаскиваются; если пользователь регистрируется, то в сессию записывается его данные.
**А проблема вот в чём:** некоторые данные должны записываться по ходу пользования, но почему-то на сайте сразу при запуске выдает ошибку, приведу пример:

```
Undefined array key "id" in ... on line 5
```

Хотя в файле нужный id запишется в сессию только после того, как пройдёт авторизация.

```
$id = $_SESSION['id'];
```

Весь код отрабатывал прекрасно на данном хосте до смены домена. Хочется отметить, что в путях проблем нет.

Я в бэкэнде пару месяцев, не могу понять, где зайцы прячутся в данной ситуации, тяжело описать суть проблемы чётко и понятно, поэтому использую такую подачу материала.

Comment: Возможно, у моих ошибок есть конкретное название? Если есть, назовите пожалуйста.

Comment: на старом хосте мб отключено было отображение варнингов в конфиге пхп вот и все

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ваша проблема решаемая, у вас включен режим логирования и предупреждений, ошибок от PHP. Для того, чтобы этого избежать, отредактируйте файл .htaccess. Пропишите следующие строки:

```
php_flag display_startup_errors off
php_flag display_errors off
php_flag html_errors off
```

Либо в коде сайта в самом начале выполните код:

```
error_reporting(0)
```

Также, можно отредактировать php.ini в случае доступа к этому файлу на сервере. Найдите данную настройку:

```
display_errors = on
```

и отключите ее, чтобы не видеть сообщения-нотисы о сессии и прочих ошибках.
Хотя подчеркну, что такой подход только сокроет ваши текущие ошибки, которые выскакивают на новом сервере. Чтобы их решить и исправить правильно было разобраться с кодом сайта, устранить дублирование регистрации в сессии. Для того, чтобы помочь в этом, мне нужно больше информации о вашем коде касательно сессии. Возможно, нужно добавить проверки логина в сессии, задать время сессии и т.д. кроме того высока вероятность, что на сайте вашем уже были логические ошибки в коде, которые выявились только сейчас.

Comment: То есть чем решать проблему и исправлять ошибку, проще её тупо скрыть?

Comment: @SemyonBayandin, нет решать проблему надо, конечно, но если он хочет добиться того, чтобы все было также, как старом сервере, то проще отключить вывод ошибок. Хотя подчеркну, решать проблему нужно.

Comment: Конкретно моя проблема, связанная с выводом ошибок, решена. Что хочу добавить: мне кажется мои ошибки появлялись из-за неправильной архитектуры сайта. Т. к. это мой первый проект, то это изначально не было учтено.

Comment: Один из тех ответов, за которые мы все так ненавидим этот сайт. 70 человек приходили сюда в поисках ответа на вопрос, как решить проблему с сессиями, а получили ответ, как выстрелить себе в ногу. А потом на мете сплошные стоны "Ах, почему люди из гугля ходят куда угодно, только не нанаш уютненький сайтик?111". Потому что вместо ответов вот такой позор